# How to create a service (windows) from a java application WITHOUT a wrapper?

Tags: java, service, wrapper

I've seen a lot of people asking how to make a java application a service and the answer is always a wrapper (i.e. JSW).

I'd like to know what makes a java application turn into a service and how to implement it without the wrapper.

I don't mean to re-invent the wheel, it just makes me feel "weaker" to not handle the concepts behind this issue.

Comment: Make a native service, I would say it's not possible.  Make a service "like" application would take some work, but would be possible.  The question is, do you need to the extra work (like writing the Thread locks and monitors to stop/pause/resume/start the service.  Install the service in the right locations to get it to run at the system start up...and user permissions???)

Comment: It's just knowledge hunger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows is not Lunix. Linux service is just a shell script that implements options like start, stop, restart. Windows service is a native component that implements well defined interface. JVM does not implement such interface, so you need something that does it and runs java.

There are several such components. I know JavaService and Apache Daemon and suggest you to use them. I do not believe that there is something "weaker" and I do not think that mentioned solutions are too heavy. JavaService is just a small DLL.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I'd vote you but I stil don't have my reputation. So basically a wrapper will act on the binary file and execute it like a service?

Comment: @FeleMed you should 'accept' the answer that you find most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_wrapper:

> "Java itself doesn't support creating system services"

Comment: I agree, yet I'd like to know "what makes a java application TURN into a service", so basically what does a wapper do to your application.

Comment: The wrapper does the grunt work of starting up and maintaining your service in the background. It also provides an interface for interacting with your service. I would google "services vs applications", they have different intentions.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not compile to native executables (.exe files for !indows or Linux elf executables). The only way that Java classes are executed are inside a Java Virtual Machine which is why you type `java -cp Main` when starting the Java application. This is also why Java binaries can be executed on multiple platforms, no matter which platform created the class and jar files.

Services are just executables that are started by the operating system at some point in time (at startup for instance). Creating such services are completely separate from Java, since they are an operating system concern. If you want to know more about services, I suggest looking up the creation of 'services' (or whatever the platform you are working on calls them) on the relevant websites. You could even look at the source code for an existing wrapper library for details, but you will inevitably have to use a language **other than Java** to implement services for your OS.

There is no weakness in using existing wrapper libraries to avoid native coding n other languages at least. As you said, do not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know why these wrappers are needed, you can look at their source code (some of them are open source).

The executables normally used to run applications (`java.exe` and `javaw.exe`) have nothing to handle the signals required to run a service. In particular, while it's easy to start an application, notifying a service application that it needs to stop and restart is another matter. You need something to catch those notifications while the application is running, and it's certainly better if this is not an abrupt process termination.

Besides the registration aspects of the service, service wrappers also implement some JNI functions, to make your application aware that it's a service. (The also tend to use the JVM DLL instead of the executable as far as I'm aware.)

Have a look at the [Winrun4J code](https://github.com/poidasmith/winrun4j) for example. It has native sections and Java sections.

In addition, services also need to be aware of certain tricks. For example, [if you don't use `-Xrs`, your service will be shut down when the user logs off](https://superuser.com/q/374147/42341).